# Laravel 5.3 return Auth:user() by uniqueidentifier

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3, uniqueidentifier

It took a while, but I figured out how to succesfully authenticate a user in Laravel 5.3 using a custom user table, with custom username and password fields.

I needed to alter my User model:

```
protected $table        = 'Contact';    
protected $primaryKey   = 'ContactId';

public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->New_hashedpassword;
}
```

The LoginController Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'EMailAddress1';
}
```

For testing, I also changed the redirection in the LoginController:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    dd(Auth::user());
}
```

After a successful login, the correct User model is passed to the browser.

The only problem I face now, is that this custom table uses a MSSQL uniqueidentifier as primary key. So now that when I call Auth::user()->someUserAttribute, my Laravel app throws an error:

```
[SQL Server]Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int (SQL: select top 1 * from [Contact] where [Contact].[ContactId] = 7164)
```

For some reason, the actual ContactID for this user (which is a string "07164BAE-33AE-E511-AE88-000C29C93884") is converted to an int resulting in "7164".

I do not understand why the LoginController can access the Auth::user() without any problem, but anywhere else in the application accessing Auth::user() throws an error.

TIA,
Wouter

**EDIT**

When I edit my User model as Jeff suggests, by adding the getAuthIdentifier and hardcoding my test user's UUID, the Auth::user() object can be accessed successfully. But how do I tell Laravel to convert to ContactId to a string instead of an integer?

```
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    //return $this->ContactId;      
    return '07164BAE-33AE-E511-AE88-000C29C93884';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. The trick is to let Laravel know the primary key field is of type string by disabeling the auto increment of the primary key by adding this to the User model:

```
protected $table        = 'Contact';    
protected $primaryKey   = 'ContactId';
public $incrementing    = false;
```

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for posting the answer.
(I have the same problem.  UUID's for Primary Keys to allow for Sharding the DB. )

Comment: Thank you for this answer, helped me fix an issue where related model records were returning inconsistently, lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

Trying overwriting this method in your user model

```
/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->ContactId;
}
```

Note: this method is parto of the "Authenticable" trait.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Jeff, this did not work. I also tried to cast ContactId explicitly to string  "return (string) $this->ContactId", but that didn't help either. This used to work in Laravel 4.2

Comment: and is really necessary to use this "ContactId" as primary key for the users table ? What if you add the "id" column (without deleting the ContactId) ?

Comment: unfortunately, that is not an option.