# Error in Laravel Eloquent relationships ::with uids as primary key

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship, uid

I'm trying to use relationships with '::with' in my project, but I get a strange error.

The entities are:

- Binary -> PK: BinaryUid
- Template -> PK: TemplateUid
- TemplateBinary -> PK: TemplateBinaryUid / FK: BinaryUid, TemplateUid

Yes, I'm working with UIDs, not incremental IDs.

Relations in Models:

- Binary:

```
public function templates() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Template::class,'TemplateBinary','BinaryUid','TemplateUid','BinaryUid','TemplateUid');
}
```

- Template:

```
public function binaries() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Binary::class,TemplateBinary::class,'TemplateUid','BinaryUid','TemplateUid','BinaryUid');
}
```

- TemplateBinary:

```
class TemplateBinary extends Pivot {
    // Whatever
}
```

Data in Binary entity:

```
"BinaryUid": "0607B8E6-A7AE-EB11-80FB-0050562E716F"
```

Data in Template entity:

```
"TemplateUid": "03D499C4-845C-47D9-A1C9-BBD4DA242B8A"
```

Data in TemplateBinary entity:

```
"BinaryUid": "0607B8E6-A7AE-EB11-80FB-0050562E716F",
"TemplateUid": "03D499C4-845C-47D9-A1C9-BBD4DA242B8A"
```

In BinaryController I'm doing:

```
Binary::with('templates')->get();
```

And this is what I get:

*Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with smallint (SQL: select [Template].*, [TemplateBinary].[BinaryUid] as [pivot_BinaryUid], [TemplateBinary].[TemplateUid] as [pivot_TemplateUid] from [Template] inner join [TemplateBinary] on [Template].[TemplateUid] = [TemplateBinary].[TemplateUid] where [TemplateBinary].[BinaryUid] in (607)) in file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\checklist\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 678*

As you can see, the 'where' condition is trying to compare with an Integer number, but I can confirm this is not an incremental ID of any entity. It has no reason to compare with incremental IDs, though. I don't know where it comes from, and why Eloquent sets this condition. What can I do?

Comment: Seems very similar to this question, [Laravel 5.3 return Auth:user() by uniqueidentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520278/laravel-5-3-return-authuser-by-uniqueidentifier). Notice also that in both cases the smallint/int in the error message is the decimal digits that start off the GUID - in your case `0607`, in theirs `07164`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it had to do with Uids being used as keys.

On each Model I've overwritten these variables:

```
$primaryKey = 'BinaryUid';
$incrementing = false;
$keyType = 'string';
$timestamps = false;
```

I recommend [this post](https://kim-jangwook.medium.com/use-uuid-as-primary-key-of-laravel-eloquent-orm-82e3db36cb62) for those working with UIDs in Laravel.